# What object to use for calculating confidence interval

Tags: r

I'm trying to find out if the inclusion of an interaction term between two variables contributes substantially to the dependent variable.

My regression model is [AGE, RISK, BEDS, AFF, AVDAILY, NURSES] and the interaction is between AGE and AFF and the dependent variable is SLENGTH

I'm attempting to find the 95% confidence interval and know to use confint() but i'm not sure what enter for the object.

I've seen in general examples:

```
mod<-lm(X~Y)
confint(mod, 0.950
```

but i'm not sure what to use in place of 'mod' for my example.

My idea was to do

```
mod<-lm(SLENGTH~AGE+RISK+BEDS+AFF+AVDAILY+NURSES)
confint(mod, AGE+AFF, 0.95)
```

as I assume the parameters to be given confidence interval are AGE+AFF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `confint(mod,"AGE:AFF",level=0.95)` will do for interaction. You can check the `?confint`, and many examples have been given.

Comment: If you are wanting to test the interaction, i would suggest using anova

Comment: You code `mod<-lm(SLENGTH~AGE+RISK+BEDS+AFF+AVDAILY+NURSES)`
does NOT include the interaction. You should use `AGE*AFF` instead of `+`, or you won't get CI for interaction. The term to be used in `confint` should the one in the model (use `confint(mod)` to see all.  In your case,  use 'AGE:AFF'  as @Sixiang.Hu said.